# iTextsharp - Adding radio button image to .pdf

Tags: c#, itext

How can I add radiobutton's image to .pdf?

I used itextsharp. checked radio button's image should be reflected to .pdf

Comment: *"How can I add radiobutton's image to .pdf?"* - By image you mean an actual *bitmap* image? Or do you want to add a radio button form element? *"checked radio button's image should be reflected to .pdf"* - What do you mean by *reflected to .pdf*? That being said, what have you tried, what made you stop?

Comment: I meant from radiobutton properties, added icon as System.Drawing.Bitmap... its green checked sign as .png format. that small icon picture can be seen at .pdf too?

Comment: if (radioButton54.Checked)
            {
                Paragraph soru1 = new Paragraph(label10.Text + " " + radioButton54.Text);
                pdfDosya.Add(soru1);
            }
            else if (radioButton122.Checked)
            {
                Paragraph soru1 = new Paragraph(label10.Text + " " + radioButton122.Text);
                pdfDosya.Add(soru1);
            }
            else if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                Paragraph soru1 = new Paragraph(label10.Text + " " + radioButton1.Text);
                pdfDosya.Add(soru1);
            }

Comment: I added + radioButton54.Image but it is shown as System.Drawing.Bitmap at .pdf

Comment: So you want to add an image to the PDF which you have in the form of a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` object... Why didn't you say so from the start, nobody reading your question would have guessed that. (just in case you wonder why your question has three down votes and 4 close votes...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comments it became clear that the OP wants to add a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` image (which he happened to retrieve from the `Image` property of a GUI radio button) to a PDF.

You use an image in a PDF with iText via its `iTextSharp.text.Image` class.

```
System.Drawing.Image drawingImage = radioButton54.Image;
iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(drawingImage, BaseColor.WHITE);
image.ScaleToFit(10, 10);
```

If you want to add it inline to a paragraph, you wrap it into a `Chunk` and then add it to a paragraph side by side with the text:

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.Add("Hello, World!");
paragraph.Add(new Chunk(image, 0, 0));
paragraph.Add("Bye, World!");
document.Add(paragraph);
```

Using an example image I have at hands, this creates something like:

[image: Example screen shot]

Comment: Hi mkl, it works great now. sorry to describe problem complicated.